# How to block users based on country using .htaccess and GeoIP?

Tags: .htaccess, redirect, geoip, country

Is there a simple way, for those of us who use shared-hosting to block users visiting from specific countries? I know I can block specific IPs (including long lists of country-IPs) but I'd rather use something like GeoIP (http://freegeoip.net); but I'm unsure of how this can be implemented into the .htaccess file?

I understand this is probably a fairly basic question, thanks for reading.

Comment: The GeoIP modules would need to be loaded and installed by your host. Are you sure they're installed? If not, you can't use it.

Answer (score 0):

MaxMind provide an Apache httpd 2.2+ module to lookup their [GeoLite2](http://dev.maxmind.com/geoip/geoip2/geolite2/) database.

https://github.com/maxmind/mod_maxminddb

They also provide an example of config to block by country

```
MaxMindDBEnable On
MaxMindDBFile DB /usr/local/share/GeoIP/GeoLite2-Country.mmdb
MaxMindDBEnv MM_COUNTRY_CODE DB/country/iso_code

SetEnvIf MM_COUNTRY_CODE ^(RU|DE|FR) BlockCountry
Deny from env=BlockCountry
```

You could use the `SetEnvIf` in main config and then `Deny` in your `.htaccess` files wherever you need to